# How to test SSRS reports manually

Tags: reporting-services, manual-testing

Can anyone help me how to test SSRS reports manually?
I am new to testing ETL reports, I have a tool SSRS in my organization and they want me to test SSRS reports. I can write SQL queries to perform data validation but I am not sure how to test the reports manually.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **ETL Reports** - are they reports triggered by an ETL? I would run the reports from the report server to make sure they run without error. It would show that the report works with the deployed dataset and permissions.

Comment: I meant QA testing of SSRS reports manually, I am sorry if I confused you. I wanted to know as a QA Tester how do we test SSRS reports.

Comment: I use Microsoft Power Automate for testing reports after any configuration or server changes